# Image upload by Customer

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product

I'm new to magento. Is there any way I can get a customer to upload an image when he is selecting a configurable product.

I don't know how to go through this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the 'Custom options' tab in the product edit page in the admin panel. That allows you to add different types of fields that the customer can fill in. There is an option for 'file' inputs also. You can even restrict the file extensions.
[Here is a screen cast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HbSH2cPrdo). It's a little old, when magento did not support file custom options, but it should give you a good idea on how it works.

Comment: can i make this field at the top of other attributes?

Comment: I think you need to move things around in your layout or your product view template. but I'm not sure what.